# Ruby installation exited with Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I was installing ruby on my mac with os x 10.8.5 using following command:

> $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

and all of sudden I got following errors:

> Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',
>
> please read /Users/home/.rvm/log/1380202439_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
>
> Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

and this is the content of log file:

> [2013-09-26 17:03:59] requirements_osx_port_update_system
>   requirements_osx_port_update_system () {
>       __rvm_try_sudo port -dv selfupdate || return $? } current path: /Users/home/.rvm/src/rvm command(2):
>   requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247 DEBUG: Copying
>   /Users/home/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to
>   /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences DEBUG: MacPorts
>   sources location:
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
>   --->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync receiving file list ... done base.tar
>
> sent 13396 bytes  received 10185 bytes  3627.85 bytes/sec total size
>   is 4925440  speedup is 208.87 receiving file list ... done
>   base.tar.rmd160
>
> sent 64 bytes  received 635 bytes  199.71 bytes/sec total size is 512 
>   speedup is 0.73 DEBUG: successful verification with key
>   /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp
>   -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar
>   MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed, DEBUG: Rebuilding and
>   reinstalling MacPorts if needed MacPorts base version 2.2.0
>   downloaded.
>   --->  Updating the ports tree Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar DEBUG:
>   /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after 
>   rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
>   receiving file list ... done ports.tar
>
> sent 51725 bytes  received 31635 bytes  11114.67 bytes/sec total size
>   is 54435840  speedup is 653.02 DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv
>   --delete-after  rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar.rmd160
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
>   receiving file list ... done ports.tar.rmd160
>
> sent 64 bytes  received 636 bytes  155.56 bytes/sec total size is 512 
>   speedup is 0.73 DEBUG: successful verification with key
>   /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp
>   -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
>   DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after
>   rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/PortIndex_darwin_12_i386/PortIndex
>   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
>   receiving file list ... done PortIndex
>   "~/.rvm/log/1380202439_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log" 176L, 8429C

Comment: what happens when you run: `sudo port -dv selfupdate || echo "error:$?"`

Answer (score 2):

You should uninstall macports... homebrew and macports don't mix well. issue the command from the terminal:

```
$ sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

You may also need to clean up homebrew

```
$ brew cleanup
```

Then you should be able to install via homebrew.

Comment: What if I need both of them?

Comment: you'll have to do something creative with the install paths... see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/181337/is-it-safe-to-install-both-homebrew-and-macports-on-the-same-machine